# Why call preInstantiateSingletons()

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Reading Pro Spring 2.5 I have a question to what's happening on page 90 i listing 4-19.

They show an example of a "ShutdownHook" where they make a bean factory, then invoke `factory.preInstantiateSingletons()` and then they get the bean from the factory in the normal way.

> By default, Spring lazily instantiates singleton beans as they are needed. This is a problem 
>   for the `ShutdownHookBean`, becuse it needs to be instantiated to
>   register itself as a shutdown hook. Invoking
>   `preInstantiateSingletons()` causes Spring to run through all its
>   singleton bean definitions and create the instances, invoking any
>   callback methods as appropiriate.

I don't understand it. Isn't the bean created anyway when you are calling `getBean(...)`? Why the need of invoking `preInstantiateSingletons()` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you may create beans, such as `ShutdownHookBean` that are never directly referenced (i.e. `getBean()` is never called to force the instantiation). By allowing you to force initialization you are ensuring that the call to

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(myShutdownHookThread);
```

is invoked are that the code in `myShutdownHookThread` will be called on JVM shutdown.

I haven't seen the code from the pro spring book, but say you need to register a shutdown hook that calls a service that is created by spring. You decide to do this a class, `ShutdownHookBean`.

Also, say you need to have a reference to `MyService` in the shutdown code.

Your bean might look like this:

```
public class ShutdownHookBean implements Runnable {

    private final MyService service;

    //MyService wired in by spring, (could be @Autowired etc).
    public ShutdownHookBean(MyService service) {

         this.service = service;

         Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(this);

    }

    public void run() {
          service.performShutdown();
    }

}
```

The `ShutdownHookBean` is created by spring only when `getBean()` is called, but since no other bean needs to reference it, nothing ever calls `getBean()`. Hence you need to force the instatiation of `ShutdownHookBean` to fire the call to `addShutdownHook()`.

Another use case that springs to mind is that you may wish to force initialization of beans at startup to validate any runtime configuration and fail fast if there are issues

Comment: What do you mean by never directly referenced? Won't you need to get a reference to it in order to add it as a shutdownhook?

Comment: @Viper - I fleshed out the example a bit more